# getting the error even after setting JAVA_HOME property

Tags: java, linux, google-app-engine, java-home

This is the error that i get when i try to run the application based upon google app engine through netbeans. But i have set the `JAVA_HOME` variable :*(see the pic)*

[image]

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/Guestbook/nbproject/build-impl.xml:550: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/Guestbook/nbproject/build-impl.xml:300: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre"
```

Then why do i get the errors ?

Comment: reason for downvote please ! :-||

Answer (score 0):

Exporting environment variables in the terminal is only limited to your current terminal session. You should edit the **.bashrc** file in you home folder for a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep using jdk1.7, add java home to /home/yourname/.bashrc or /etc/profile file
shell code:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and run "source .bashrc" command.

if you only run one time, add env parameter.
for example:

```
env JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02  mvn clean install
```

Comment: what is _source_ in source.bashrc ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta `source` is the command which actually executes the file. `.bashrc` is the file name. Please note that `.`(dot) is a part of file name as it's a hidden file.

Comment: @Garbage did you see what result i got when i executed that command

Comment: @SuhailGupta There should be a space between source and .bashrc

Please copy paste following:

`source .bashrc`